# How to add a column in pandas DataFrame with boolean result of datetime comparison?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

How can I create an extra column in a Pandas DataFrame that contains the result (boolean) of the following date comparison?

```
records['old'] = TRUE if records['date'] is older than 180 days
records['old'] = FALSE if records['date'] is not older than 180 days
```

**Code**

```
today = datetime.now()
records['old'] = records[abs(today - pd.to_datetime(records['date'])) > 180]
```

**Output**

> TypeError: invalid type comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `pd.Timedelta` or [`dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
records['old'] = abs(today - pd.to_datetime(records['date'])) > pd.Timedelta(180, unit='d')
```

Or:

```
records['old'] = abs(today - pd.to_datetime(records['date'])).dt.days > 180
```

Sample:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-12-30', periods=10)
records = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng, 'a': range(10)})  

today = pd.datetime.now()
records['old'] = abs(today - pd.to_datetime(records['date'])) > pd.Timedelta(5, unit='d')
print (records)
   a       date    old
0  0 2017-12-30   True
1  1 2017-12-31   True
2  2 2018-01-01   True
3  3 2018-01-02   True
4  4 2018-01-03   True
5  5 2018-01-04   True
6  6 2018-01-05   True
7  7 2018-01-06  False
8  8 2018-01-07  False
9  9 2018-01-08  False
```